# TikZ matrix vs. shapes.multipart vs. text width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-shape

I'm wondering if anyone can make sense of the error I get when I try to set the text width in a matrix of multipart nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={font=\large\sffamily},
every two node part/.style={font=\normalsize\sffamily,%text width=0.5cm %<- causes an error
}]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false}%,text width=0.5cm %<- causes an error
    ] {
      top\nodepart{two}some lengthy text at the bottom & x\nodepart{two} y\\
       x\nodepart{two} y & top\nodepart{two}bottom \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Each attempt to set the `text width` causes an error.

It has been stated by Ulrike Fischer that

> All options starting with text such as text width have no effect.

in a matrix. I'd be happy to believe that if it was not for the following counterexample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw},text width=0.5cm 
    ] {
      top some lengthy text at the bottom & x  y\\
       x  y & top bottom \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my humble opinion this shows that it is possible to set the text width in a matrix of non-multipart nodes.

**NEW INSIGHTS(?)**: One actually *can* set the size of multipart nodes, at least to some extent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={font=\large\sffamily},
every two node part/.style={font=\normalsize\sffamily,%text width=0.5cm %<- causes an error
}]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false}%,text width=0.5cm %<- causes an error
    ] {
      top\nodepart[text width=1.5cm]{two}some lengthy text at the bottom & 
      x\nodepart{two} y\\
       x\nodepart{two} y & top\nodepart{two}bottom \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, repeating this trick at any of the right (right-most?) nodes fails. Yet one can add empty nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={font=\large\sffamily},
every two node part/.style={font=\normalsize\sffamily,text width=1cm %<- causes an error
}]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false}%,text width=0.5cm %<- causes an error
    ] {
      top\nodepart{two}some lengthy text at the bottom & 
      x\nodepart{two} y &\\
       x\nodepart{two} y & top\nodepart{two}bottom &\\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ACKNOWLEDGMENTS**: I acknowledge useful comments by Torbjørn T., Ulrike Fischer, Dr. Manuel Kuehner and @cfr.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to set the text width of the multipart nodes in a matrix of nodes?

Comment: "All options starting with text such as text width have no effect." in a matrix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then please compile the second example. It does work there. (And sorry for the misleading comment in the TeX file.)

Comment: It's not ignored, you're using the wrong style name.  You have `\nodepart{two}`, so it should be `every two node part/.style={..}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, you are right. My mistake. However, if I do as you suggest I am back to the error.

Comment: I took the liberty adding screenshots of each MWE, hope that's ok.

Comment: Please just edit the addendum into your question: the example with the wrong syntax isn't relevant because the question is the same even when that's corrected. At least, that's what I would think. What does @TorbjørnT. think?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Doesn't that refer to options passed to the node which is the matrix and not to the nodes which constitute that matrix?

Comment: 'For multi-part shapes you can only set the text part of the node.' You are trying to set something else, so it can't work.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for all the comments! And sorry, I do not understand the last comment. If you mean that I cannot set the width of a part of a node without affecting the rest, I agree, and of course setting the widths of all parts would be also fine. Yet I can't make this work (either).

Comment: @cfr ... and actually one can, to some extent, set the width of the parts... please have a look at my "new" "insights". What seems to break is an attempt to set the width of a part of the *right-most* nodes (I "checked" that by making the matrix larger).

Comment: @marmot It is a quote from the manual. In a matrix, you can only set the text part of the node: you can't set the two part or whatever. At least, that's how I'd understand it.

Comment: @cfr I would be happy to believe you if there were not the counterexamples. I added one more, which may already be a viable workaround for anybody trying to put multipart nodes in a matrix and set their width: just add an empty row at the right. Empirically, this seems to work, but I can at best guess why it works.

Comment: It should work without the `matrix of nodes` and entering nodes manually.

Comment: @percusse Thanks! Would you mind spelling this out in an answer?

Comment: @marmot I'm just quoting the manual. It isn't a question of believing me or not. You're saying the manual is wrong. Or is there a better interpretation? I said I didn't know what it meant.

Comment: @marmot I haven't checked why it screws up with `matrix of nodes` at the end column, just guessing here.